# Can't click on a context menu item with Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

I want to make automated tests with Katalon Studio. The problem is that I can't click on a context menu item because when I do that the click event does not hit the item, but what is beneath it. So if there is a button beneath my context menu this button gets clicked instead of the context menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Katalon error: Unable to click on object ... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/katalon-error-unable-to-click-on-object-other-element-would-receive-the-cli)

Comment: No beacause in that case the elements I clicked on was not present because the page was loading. Meanwhile in this case the element exists.

Answer (score 3):

More information would be helpful to help solve your case (screenshot, video, DOM information of that element).

Here I'll try to give you a common solution: you need to add a timeout to wait for the context menu to appear on the screen.

- You can do that by using the keyword [Wait For Element Visible](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/%5BWebUI%5D+Wait+For+Element+Visible) to check for visibility of the specified element or using the keyword [Wait For Element Attribute Value](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/%5BWebUI%5D+Wait+For+Element+Attribute+Value) to wait for a specific attribute that could indicate the visibility of that element.
- If those keywords failed, you can add a hard delay using the delay keyword before trying to click on that context menu.