# Element is not clickable (the button is blocking by other element)

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image: Trying to click this button id="btnSearch"]

I'm trying to click on this button: `browser.find_element_by_id('btnSearch')`

But this button is blocking by this div tag: `<div id="actionSearch" class="row pull-right">`

How do I go around to click this button with id='btnSearch" while it's blocking by the actionSearch div?

I tried the following:

- `browser.find_element_by_id('btnSearch').click()`
- ```
  browser.implicitly_wait(10)
  el = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSearch"]')
  ActionChains(browser).move_to_element_with_offset(el, 1827, 270)
  ActionChains(browser).click()
  ActionChains(browser).perform()
  ```
- ```
  element = browser.find_element_by_id('btnSearch')
  browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
  ```
- ```
  wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, //*[@id="btnSearch"]'))).click()
  ```

none of these work.

Can anyone help me with this? I've spent two days trying to click this button!! Please help!

Comment: What exceptions occurs for the different options you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Comment: Check this [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498)

Comment: To find out if it is a duplicate, at least it must be known which exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Considering provided image of HTML source (tip: do not provide it as image, but as text instead) I can assume that required element located in the bottom of page and you might need to scroll page down to be able to handle it.

Try below code

```
link = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearch")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", link)
link.click()
```

Note that link is not a pseudo-element (is not located inside `::before`/`::after` pseudo-element), so it can not be the cause of your problem

As for your code:

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element_with_offset(el, 1827, 270)
ActionChains(browser).click()
ActionChains(browser).perform()
```

Here you're trying to make scroll to link with huge offset and then you make click on current mouse position - **not on link**

You can try to modify it as

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(el)
ActionChains(browser).click(el)  # Pass WebElement you want to click as argument to `click()`
ActionChains(browser).perform()
```

Comment: Thanks you for taking your time to answer! I'll try this tomorrow when I get back to work. 

I just found out that the reason the element is not clickable is because  the above div id= "actionSearch" is blocking the button that i'm trying to click.

I really hope your solution work. Can't wait to try it tomorrow.

Comment: It didn't work.

I got this:

essage: unknown error: Element <a id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-yellow">...</a> is not clickable at point (1827, 270). Other element would receive the click: <div class="k-overlay" style="display: block; z-index: 10002; opacity: 0.5;"></div>

Comment: Can you try to add `wait(browser, 10).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, //div[@class="k-overlay"]')))` before handling link?

Comment: Not sure if i add it correctly: Here what i did:      
      
`wait(browser, 10).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="k-overlay"]')))
link = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearch")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", link)
link.click()`


Error Message: 
`-> 132             wait(browser, 10).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="k-overlay"]')))

---> 96      raise TimeoutException(message)TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure how to solve the issue since I cannot fully understand the behavior of target web-app? Can you share page URL or it's not public?

Comment: Sorry it's not public. 

I think there is other component overlapping here (some other component of the DOM) 

The second answer of this thread give some possible solutions, but it's in java. I don't know java.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv

Anyway thanks you for taking your time to help!

Comment: Yep, obviously something overlapping the link :) The problem is how to get rid of click interception... I see `<div class="k-overlay">` on your image and it's right above the link. Can you check how it looks like when page rendered? Does it has fixed position just like the navigation bar on this SO page? Do you need to scroll little more to see the link?

Comment: I uploaded two pictures here: https://imgur.com/a/njo3c

When I hover on the '<div class="k-overlay">' the whole thing highlight. 

When I hover on the '<div id="actionSearch">, both search and Reset are highlight. I think that's the reason I can't on search button?

Comment: Can you try this little hack `driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("div.k-overlay").display="none";')` instead of `wait(browser, 10).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, //div[@class="k-overlay"]')))` ?

Comment: Error Message: `<a id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-yellow">...</a> is not clickable at point (1827, 270). Other element would receive the click: <div class="k-overlay" style="display: block; z-index: 10002; opacity: 0.5;"></div>`

I used this:
`browser.execute_script('document.querySelector("div.k-overlay").display="none";')

link = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearch")browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", link) link.click()`

Comment: I really appreciate you taking time to help figuring this out!

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be `browser.execute_script('document.querySelector("div.k-overlay").style.display="none";')`

Comment: Still couldn't click it. 

Is it possible to disable style on this `<div id="actionSearch" class="row pull-right">`?

Comment: Another suggestion: just try to replace `link.click()` with `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', link)`