# python / selenium / Element is not clickable

Tags: python, selenium

I have just started to learn python and tried to make a little project where I do some interaction with a website, but I have a little problem and I am not able to solve it myself.

I am trying to find some stuff on a website. Therefore I enter some criteria and press then the search button. If my search is successful, new information appears on the website and I would like to hit a button, do some other actions and go back to the search side. If there is no result, I go back to the search site.

The code works fine for most of the time, but sometimes I receive an error and my code interrupts.

```
#click search button
css = 'button.btn-standard:nth-child(2)'
iElement = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css)
iElement.click()

#wait some time
t = random.uniform(0.190, 0.25)
time.sleep(t)
        
css = 'body > main > section > section > div.ut-navigation-container-view--content > div > div > section.ut-navigation-container-view.ui-layout-right > div > div > div.DetailPanel > div.bidOptions > button.btn-standard.buyButton.currency-coins'
try:            
  #Check if search is successful
  iElements = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css)

  #Buy now for n coins
  iElement = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css)
  iElement.click() # <- here is were the error occurs

  .... some other code that works...          
except NoSuchElementException:
  a = 1

#Go back
css = '.ut-navigation-button-control'
iElement = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css)
iElement.click()
```

Error: ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at point (972,569) because another element  obscures it

I have already tried `element_to_be_clickable` but I was not able to handle it.

Can somebody help me with my problem?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please add the whole error to your original post so it is easier for others to help you. And what does it mean that you were not able to handle element to be clickable?

Comment: You have exact error "Element is not clickable at point" so You must watch how elements are displayed on the page, maybe one obscures Your element that You want click. Do You have problem with meaning "obscures"?. We cannot help You without knowing target page structure.

Comment: @MateMrše The complete error message is:
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-eaf6fd3d101d> in <module>
     74             print('Treffer bei Suche-Nr:', i+1)
     75             iElement = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css)
---> 76             iElement.click()
....
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="btn-standard buyButton currency-coins"> is not clickable at point (972,569) because another element <div class="ut-click-shield showing interaction"> obscures it

Answer (score 0):

An element is overlapping your element try using this instead.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",  iElement)
```

To wait and click on it

```
iElement=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css)))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I guess I have not done it correct, because I still get an error
```#Buy now for n coins
#iElement = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css)
#iElement.click()
iElement = WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css)))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",  iElement)
iElement.click()```
Without iElement.click() there is no error, but the button will not be clicked

Comment: Remove the second click and increase time.

Answer (score 0):

So, an element with class "ut-click-shield" is blocking the click, as the name implies. There are some things you can try:

a) Add a "wait for element clickable" before actually clicking the element:

```
iElement = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS, "myElement"))).click()
```

b) Another option is using [Actions Chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252880/element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-5-because-another-element-obscures-it#49261182):

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element((By.CSS, "myElement")).click().perform()
```

c) For an overview of different "Element not clickable" reasons see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: still get the same error if I use
```#Buy now for n coins
#iElement = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css)
#iElement.click()
iElement = WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css))).click()```

Comment: You set the timeout to 2 seconds. Have you tried with a longer timeout?

Comment: If you found it useful, please accept and/or upvote my answer.