# Unable to load tables with "Load more" options in a website using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Need to scrape the full table from this site with "Load more" option.

As of now when I`m scraping , I only get the one that shows up by default on when loading the page.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from six.moves import urllib

URL2 = "https://www.mykhel.com/football/indian-super-league-player-stats-l750/"
header = {'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
          'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                        "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
          }

resp2 = requests.get(url=URL2, headers=header).text

tables2 = pd.read_html(resp2)
overview_table2= tables2[0]
overview_table2
```

|  | Player Name | Team | Matches | Goals | Time Played | Unnamed: 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jorge Pereyra Diaz | Mumbai City | 9 | 6 | 538 Mins | NaN |
| 1 | Cleiton Silva | SC East Bengal | 8 | 5 | 707 Mins | NaN |
| 2 | Abdenasser El Khayati | Chennaiyin FC | 5 | 4 | 231 Mins | NaN |
| 3 | Lallianzuala Chhangte | Mumbai City | 9 | 4 | 737 Mins | NaN |
| 4 | Nandhakumar Sekar | Odisha | 8 | 4 | 673 Mins | NaN |
| 5 | Ivan Kalyuzhnyi | Kerala Blasters | 7 | 4 | 428 Mins | NaN |
| 6 | Bipin Singh | Mumbai City | 9 | 4 | 806 Mins | NaN |
| 7 | Noah Sadaoui | Goa | 8 | 4 | 489 Mins | NaN |
| 8 | Diego Mauricio | Odisha | 8 | 3 | 526 Mins | NaN |
| 9 | Pedro Martin | Odisha | 8 | 3 | 263 Mins | NaN |
| 10 | Dimitri Petratos | ATK Mohun Bagan | 6 | 3 | 517 Mins | NaN |
| 11 | Petar Sliskovic | Chennaiyin FC | 8 | 3 | 662 Mins | NaN |
| 12 | Holicharan Narzary | Hyderabad | 9 | 3 | 705 Mins | NaN |
| 13 | Dimitrios Diamantakos | Kerala Blasters | 7 | 3 | 529 Mins | NaN |
| 14 | Alberto Noguera | Mumbai City | 9 | 3 | 371 Mins | NaN |
| 15 | Jerry Mawihmingthanga | Odisha | 8 | 3 | 611 Mins | NaN |
| 16 | Hugo Boumous | ATK Mohun Bagan | 7 | 2 | 580 Mins | NaN |
| 17 | Javi Hernandez | Bengaluru | 6 | 2 | 397 Mins | NaN |
| 18 | Borja Herrera | Hyderabad | 9 | 2 | 314 Mins | NaN |
| 19 | Mohammad Yasir | Hyderabad | 9 | 2 | 777 Mins | NaN |
| 20 | Load More.... | Load More.... | Load More.... | Load More.... | Load More.... | Load More.... |

But I need the full table , including the data under "Load more", please help.

Answer (score 4):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0'
}


def main(url):
    params = {
        "action": "stats",
        "league_id": "750",
        "limit": "300",
        "offset": "0",
        "part": "leagues",
        "season_id": "2022",
        "section": "football",
        "stats_type": "player",
        "tab": "overview"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = [(x['title'], *[i.get_text(strip=True) for i in x.find_all_next('td', limit=4)])
            for x in soup.select('a.player_link')]
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        goal, columns=['Name', 'Team', 'Matches', 'Goals', 'Time Played'])
    print(df)


main('https://www.mykhel.com/src/index.php')
```

Output:

```
                      Name              Team Matches Goals Time Played
0       Jorge Pereyra Diaz       Mumbai City       9     6    538 Mins
1            Cleiton Silva    SC East Bengal       8     5    707 Mins
2    Abdenasser El Khayati     Chennaiyin FC       5     4    231 Mins
3    Lallianzuala Chhangte       Mumbai City       9     4    737 Mins
4        Nandhakumar Sekar            Odisha       8     4    673 Mins
..                     ...               ...     ...   ...         ...
268          Sarthak Golui    SC East Bengal       6     0    402 Mins
269          Ivan Gonzalez    SC East Bengal       8     0    683 Mins
270       Michael Jakobsen  NorthEast United       8     0    676 Mins
271       Pratik Chowdhary     Jamshedpur FC       6     0    495 Mins
272         Chungnunga Lal    SC East Bengal       8     0    720 Mins

[273 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you refer to the other link, an **index.php**, and where do you get those `params`? Is it a sort of API, is it documented for this website?

Comment: And what is `'lxml'` for, removing it does not change anything.

Comment: @DiMithras check [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60925669/7658985) and regarding `lxml` is just the type of parser which is the most quickest efficient one, removing it is letting the soup to use `html.parser` by default.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη ohh, cool! That explains a lot! I thought about dev tools and looked there, but missed clicking the button step. Now I can clearly see that link and params, also would make sense to put `Fetch/XHR` option to more easily find that record. Happy to learn something new today, much appreciated  Yet [tag:Selenium] remains an option, doesn't it?

Comment: @DiMithras if you think that selenium is designed for web scraping, So you've to think twice on what you learned. Selenium is created for test cases purpose only.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη also for whatever reason I don't see `Params` tab in **Firefox**, but it can be found in **Chrome** under `Payload`.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη yeah, I know it's a testing suite. As you say, "you don't need it for such a single page". But for something bigger?

Comment: @DiMithras https://i.imgur.com/DZ1F1bv.png isn't that a firefox ? and BTW it's not about small/bigger! selenium isn't for *web scraping* at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250122/discussion-between-dimithras-and--c).

Comment: Thanks Mate , but i`m not still able to understand how i`ll be able to scrape the data in other tables like "Passes" in the site.
Also the result with main(url) function is a dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamically loaded page, so you can not parse all the contents without hitting a button.
Well… may be you can with XHR or smth like that, may be someone will contribute to the answers here.

I'll stick to working with dynamically loaded pages with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation suite.

### Installation

To get started, you'll need to install [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) bindings:

```console
pip install selenium
```

You seem to already have [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup), but for anyone who might come across this answer, we'll also need it and `html5lib`, we'll need them later to parse the table:

```console
pip install html5lib BeautifulSoup4
```

Now, for [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) to work you'll need a driver installed for a browser of your choice.  To get the drivers you may use [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/#1-selenium-manager-beta), [Driver Management Software](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/#2-driver-management-software) or [download the drivers manually](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers). The above mentioned options are something new, I have my manually downloaded drivers for ages, so I'll stick to them. I'll duplicate here the download links:

| Browser | Link to driver download |
| --- | --- |
| Chrome: | https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/ |
| Edge: | https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ |
| Firefox: | https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases |
| Safari: | https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/ |
| Opera: | https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases |

You can use any browser, e.g. [Brave browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158434/how-to-run-selenium-tests-on-the-brave-web-browser), Yandex Browser, basically any Chromium based browser of your choice or even [Tor browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134419/run-tor-browser-with-selenium-webdriver) 
Anyway, it's a bit out of this answer scope, just keep in mind, for any browser and it's family you'll need a driver.

I'll stick with **Firefox**. Hence you need [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) installed and driver placed somewhere. The best option would be to [add this folder to `PATH` variable](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/#3-the-path-environment-variable).

If you choose **chromium**, you'll have to strictly stick to Chrome browser version. As for **Firefox**, I have a pretty old *geckodriver 0.29.1* and it works like a charm with the latest update.

## Hands on

```python
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

URL2 = "https://www.mykhel.com/football/indian-super-league-player-stats-l750/"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL2)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()=' Load More.... ']")
while(element.is_displayed()):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table')
tables2 = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
driver.close()

overview_table2 = tables2[0].dropna(how='all').dropna(axis='columns', how='all')
overview_table2.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
overview_table2
```

1. We only need `pandas` for our resulting table and `selenium` for web automation.
2. `URL2` — is the same variable you used
3. `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` — here we instantiate **Firefox** and the browser will get opened. This is where [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) magic will happen.
   **Note**: If you decided to skip adding driver to a `PATH` variable, you can directly reference your here, e.g.:

   - `webdriver.Firefox(r"C:\WebDriver\bin")`
   - `webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver"))`
4. `driver.get(URL2)` — open the desired page
5. `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()=' Load More.... ']")`
   Using xpath selector we find a link that has the same text as your 20th row.
6. With that stored `element` we click it all the time till it disappears.
   It would be more sensible and easy to just use `element.click()`, but it results in an error. More info on other [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252880/element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-5-because-another-element-obscures-it).
7. Assign `table` variable with a corresponding element.
8. `tables2` I left this weird variable name as is in your question.
   Here we get **outerHTML** as **innnerHTML** would render contents of the `<table>` tag, but not the tag itself.
9. We should not forget to `.close()` our driver as we don't need it anymore.
10. As a result of html parsing there will be a `list` just like in question provided. I drop here the unnamed column and last empty row.

The resulting `overview_table2` looks like:

|  | Player Name | Team | Matches | Goals | Time Played |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jorge Pereyra Diaz | Mumbai City | 9.0 | 6.0 | 538 Mins |
| 1 | Cleiton Silva | SC East Bengal | 8.0 | 5.0 | 707 Mins |
| 2 | Abdenasser El Khayati | Chennaiyin FC | 5.0 | 4.0 | 231 Mins |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 270 | Michael Jakobsen | NorthEast United | 8.0 | 0.0 | 676 Mins |
| 271 | Pratik Chowdhary | Jamshedpur FC | 6.0 | 0.0 | 495 Mins |
| 272 | Chungnunga Lal | SC East Bengal | 8.0 | 0.0 | 720 Mins |

#### Side note

Job done. As some further improvement you may play with different browsers and try the [headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python), a mode when browser does not open on you desktop environment, but rather runs silently in the background.