# unknown error: Elemen is not clickable at point (1327, 310). Other element would receive the click:

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i am getting this error :

```
unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1327, 310). Other element would receive the click
```

I am using chrome Browser Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit) , ChromeDriver 2.36 and my selenium jar is Selenium Standalone Server 3.11.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Comment: Which other element is receiving the click, it is mentioned in the error message, in the part you are not sharing with us. What is happening when you are running the test, is there some animation running, hiding the element which has to be clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below method to avoid this,

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement("element name").click().perform();
```

Comment: From the information available in the question it's not clear what the reason of the error is. So this answer can be a solution or not.

Comment: actually i want to click on a "Edit" button. when i run my test in firefox browser its run as per script but when  use chrome its showing unknown error.

Comment: You can try with above action method, If locator is true it will work, as its working in Firefox.

Comment: Yes its work when put thread.sleep() before actions class. thanks :)