# Error occurred after chrome browser updated to 65 in Selenium webDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing below error after my chrome browser version changed to 65.0.3325.181.

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a 
class="actionInActionBox" id="BACK" name="BACK" title="Selection Page" 
onclick="document.getElementById('ListLeftNLSelectedTop').value='Catalog_NL'; submitTopFormByAction('ListLeftNL');return false;">...</a> is not clickable at 
point (300, 20). Other element would receive the click: <div 
id="overlay_modal" class="overlay_infoWindow" style="display: block; 
position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 30; width: 100%; height: 
720px;"></div>
 (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Session ID: 451d25fe77677cb5c5dccf2f8501d752
```

I have used explicit wait when frame changes. On changing frame, page loads for some time and then click on actionInActionBox once the element is clickable. But now instead of waiting, it is directly clicking on element.

```
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(objrep.get("Content_ID")))); //Clicked on Content
        element.click();
framewait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("FrameName"));
WebElement element0 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("actionInActionBox")));
element0.click();
```

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Comment: I checked for duplicate. No duplicate present. Code was working fine but it started giving error soon after up-gradation of chrome. It works if I add Thread.sleep();. But that too gives error if loading time extends the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved on extending time for implicit wait from 5 to 20 secs.