# Selenium element is not clickable at point (chrome) in javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, ui-automation, browserstack

I'm new to Selenium and I'm running my selenium script on Browserstack.

Everything works fine, until i reach the bottom 10% of my page.

I get the following error:

> Uncaught WebDriverError: Appium error: unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (20, 324). Other
>   element would receive the click: ...
>         (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.83)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux
>   3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64 x86_64)

This is my code:

```
describe.only(testTitle, function () {
    before(function () {
        driver = driverConfiguration.getDriverConfiguration(testTitle, 'chrome')
    })
    after(function (done) {
        driver.quit().then(done)
    })
    it('Sample tests', function (done) {
        driver.get('https://www.test.com').then(function(){
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('cardNumber')).sendKeys('0000000000').then(function(){
                driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('billingLine1')).sendKeys('test');
                driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('billingLine2')).sendKeys('test');
                driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('billingCity')).sendKeys('San Jose');
                driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('agree')).click(); // ERROR!!!!!
            }).then(function() {
                driver.quit().then(done);
            })
        });
    })
})
```

**When I do the following:**

```
            // return driver.wait(function() {
            //     return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('agree')).isDisplayed();
            // }, 1000);
```

It says True. The element is visible.

**Using Chrome on Samsung Galaxy S8**

I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: I've gotten that error before but I was able to resolve it by making sure that the element was visible on the screen at the time of click.

Comment: When I try to execute this code:

 `           // return driver.wait(function() {
            //     return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('agree')).isDisplayed();
            // }, 1000);`

It does say true. i.e the element is visible.

Comment: Not sure how I can resolve this issue :( without statically coding scrolldown.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing with driver.executeScript() -- I don't know why the element had to be on the screen when its visible to the code, but it did get it to work :)

Comment: @Doug can you please let me know how do I use the executeScript() to get it working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Comment: ^^ That's java @DebanjanB

Comment: @TechnoCorner I am afraid, I thought the concept for solving this particular issue would have been same across all the bindings art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continued from comments above ...

I encountered this problem as well, when I needed to click a button but it was not visible on the screen (however, it was detected by the code).
To resolve this, I used the WebDriver's `executeScript()` method to run some JavaScript on the page to scroll until my button was in view.

```
driver.executeScript(`
    var target = document.getElementById('agree');
    var tarTop = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    document.body.scrollTop = tarTop;
`);
```

You can try `driver.executeAsyncScript()` if you want want to add a timeout to the scroll, to make sure the page has reached its destination first. At that point you'll be using async/await...

```
await driver.executeAsyncScript(`
    var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    var target = document.getElementById('agree');
    var tarTop = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    document.body.scrollTop = tarTop;
    setTimeout(()=>{ callback( true ); }, 1500);
`).then((data)=>{
    return data;
});
```

Comment: I used this and it solved my issue:


                driver.executeScript(`
                    var target = document.getElementById('agree').scrollIntoView();
                `);     

Thanks for the inputs @Doug

Answer (score 2):

You've omitted the most important part of the error message in your question

> Other element would receive the click: ...

The element in the `...` section was the element that was blocking the click. As you discovered, Selenium was reporting that the element was displayed/visible. This error message is just stating that when Selenium attempted to click on the element, another element was blocking the click. If you take a look at the HTML of the blocking element and search that in the HTML of the page, you should be able to identify the element. In my experience, it's a dialog or maybe a banner at the bottom of the page, etc. Sometimes you will need to close it, other times you will need to scroll down/up a little to get the desired element from behind the blocking UI.

Comment: Yup you are exactly right. I figured out using the same thing and I used other 'div' and it worked! Thank you @JeffC