# Best way to avoid timeout in Java Selenium TestNG when I have multiple tests in one class?

Tags: java, selenium, timeout, salesforce, testng

I have multiple tests in one class in Selenium TestNG. Problem is that nearly every time I get some timeout exception in different test or in a different step in a test. So is hard to catch exact element causing the timeout.

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
OR
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <img data-aura-rendered-by="3:3231;a" src="avatar_96.png" class="profileTrigger branding-user-profile circular" alt="User" title="User"> is not clickable at point (1887, 68). Other element would receive the click: <div class="panel slds-modal slds-modal--large slds-fade-in-open" aria-labelledby="title_1233:319;a" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" data-aura-rendered-by="1249:319;a" style="opacity: 1;">...</div>
```

What is the best way to avoid timeout in Selenium TestNG when I have multiple tests in one class?
Is there some code which I can put for instance to

```
@BeforeClass or @Beforetest
```

Which will apply for all tests in the class?

For a better understanding, I am sharing my code.

```
 public class BothApprovalCockpitLighting   {

  private static WebDriver driver;
  public static WebDriverWait wd;

  @BeforeTest
  public void setUp()
  {
      System.out.println("*******************");
      System.out.println("launching Chrome browser");
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  }

  @BeforeClass
  public void login() throws Exception
  {
       driver.get("https://test.com/"); 

       wd = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wd.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")));

        // Enter username in textbox 
        System.out.println("Enter username in textbox"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys("USERNAME" ); //Batcon


        //Enter Password in texbox 
        System.out.println("Enter Password in texbox"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("PASSWORD");

        //Click on Login button 
        System.out.println("Click on Login button"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Login']")).click(); 

        System.out.println("Login Sucessfully");
  }

  @Test(priority=1)
  public void test1DontCointainApprovalCockpit() throws Exception
  {

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='All Tabs']")).click();
      String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();

      boolean b1 = pageSource.contains("Approval");
      boolean b2 = pageSource.contains("Cockpit");


      System.out.println("Page should not cointain - Approval Cockpit. This is a negative test.");
      System.out.println("Page cointain Approval: " + b1);
      System.out.println("Page cointain Cockpit: " + b2);

      if(b1 || b2)
      {
          System.out.println("Test 1 is fail - Page cointain Approval Cockpit.");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("Test 1 is past - Page doesn´t cointain Approval Cockpit.");
      }

      Assert.assertFalse(b1,"Failed test 1 page cointain Approval");
      Assert.assertFalse(b2,"Failed test 1 page cointain Cockpit");


  }

  @Test(priority=2)
  public void test2SwitchCointain() throws Exception
  {
      String actualText1 =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Switch')])[2]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

      Assert.assertTrue(actualText1.contains("Switch to Lightning Experience"), "Failed test 2 page doesn´t cointain Switch");



  }

  @Test(priority=3)
  public void test3Switch() throws Exception
  {


       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'John')]]")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.linkText("Switch")).click();

  }

  @Test(priority=4)
  public void test4FMIRApprovalCokpit() throws Exception
  {
      driver.findElement(By.className("slds-icon-waffle")).click();
      String actualText1 =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'FIR')]]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");



      System.out.println("FIR text: " + actualText1);



      Assert.assertTrue(actualText1.contains("FMIR"), "Failed test 4 page doesn´t cointain FMIR");

  }

  @Test(priority=5)
  public void test4ApprovalCokpit() throws Exception
  {


      String actualText2 =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Cockpit')]]")).getAttribute("innerHTML"); 


      System.out.println("Cockpit text:" + actualText2);



      Assert.assertTrue(actualText2.contains("Approval Cockpit"), "Failed test 4 page doesn´t cointain Cockpit");



  }


  @Test(priority=6)
  public void test6Link() throws Exception
  {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='FIR']")).click();
  }

  @Test(priority=7)
  public void test7backToSalesforce() throws Exception
  {
      Thread.sleep(10000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='User']")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Switch to Classic")).click();
  }


  @AfterClass
  public void backToClassic() throws Exception
  {

        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='User']")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.linkText("Switch to Classic")).click(); //Not working

  }


  @AfterTest
  public void tearDown()
  {

      if(driver!=null)
      {
          System.out.println("Closing Chrome browser");
          driver.quit();
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: cant you increase the timeout in implicit wait to say 1 minute ?

Comment: No that´s not working - still same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here would be to implement a Page Object Model, and have a method that abstracts driver.findElement(By).

Then instead of calling driver.findElement directly, always call your method that is abstracting it.
E.g.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public abstract class BasePage {
        protected WebDriver driver;
        protected WebDriverWait wait;

        public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        }

        public void clickElement(By by) {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
            driver.findElement(by).click();
        }
    }
```

For each of the pages on your website, have a concrete page that extends BasePage.  Use BasePage for all your interactions through WebDriver, and you'll have a much easier time implementing "error handling" throughout your tests.