# Tried All ..Performing click but a div is not shown after click and getting error.

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying to click a button, but getting error Element is not clickable at point (1333, 75). Other element would receive the click. I am using google chrome version 65.

```html
<li class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click slds-m-left--x-small" data-aura-rendered-by="484:0">
<!--render facet: 489:0--><!--render facet: 490:0-->
<button class="bare branding-userProfile-button slds-button uiButton forceHeaderButton oneUserProfileCardTrigger" aria-live="off" type="button" data-aura-rendered-by="159:184;a" data-aura-class="uiButton forceHeaderButton oneUserProfileCardTrigger">
<!--render facet: 160:184;a-->
<!--render facet: 162:184;a-->
<div class="tooltipTrigger tooltip-trigger uiTooltip" aria-describedby="tt-for-149:184;a" tabindex="-1" data-aura-rendered-by="154:184;a" data-aura-class="uiTooltip" id="154:184;a">
<span class="photoContainer forceSocialPhoto" data-aura-rendered-by="1312:0" data-aura-class="forceSocialPhoto" style="">
<span data-aura-rendered-by="1376:0" class="uiImage" data-aura
class="uiImage">
<img data-aura-rendered-by="1374:0"
src="https://ap5.salesforce.com/_slds/images/themes/lightning_blue/lightning_blue_profile_avatar_96.png" class="profileTrigger branding-user-profile circular" alt="User" title="User">
</span>
</span>
<!--render facet: 146:184;a-->
<span class="tooltip-invisible" role="tooltip" id="tt-for-149:184;a" 
data-aura-rendered-by="156:184;a">View profile
</span>
</div>
</button>
</li>
```

Also on clicking the button  needs to be poped up.
Button X path is html/body/div[5]/div[1]/header/div[3]/span/ul/li[9]/button

```html
<div class="container" style="border:thick;color:red" data-aura-rendered-by="116:1956;a">
<!--render facet: 117:2575;a-->
</div>
```

I used following codes to perform click to solve the error but still its showing error

```
driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement element=driver.findElement('locator'));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+element.getLocation().y+")");
element.click();
```

Comment: is you are working on chrome browser

Comment: yes,and i set the property also by System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",'location of chromedriver.exe');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Comment: Yes...i understood the exception..but how to solve the error..As i tried to overcome the error by Actions class,and all..but still the same error

Comment: Tried all methods of which is described in the above link

Comment: @Jolly Priya plz go to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el

Comment: Do you wanna click on View profile button ?

Comment: html/body/div[5]/div[1]/header/div[3]/span/ul/li[9]/button , this Xpath is absolute try to write the relative Xpath like : //span[text()='View profile']

Comment: @cruisepandey its not working..

Comment: @KuldeepYadav ..went through the link but no solutions given are working..Please help

Comment: @DebanjanB Went through the link..but no solution is working

Comment: Hello all...not working with any of the solutions given in the link

Comment: @JollyPriya update or downgrade your browser or try in another browser (Mozilla)

Answer (score 0):

**Use following** code snippet in place of **moveToElement of action class**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

**OR**

Click using the JavaScriptExecutor :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: @JollyPriya : Could you please try with JavascriptExecutor click as I mentioned in the answer

Comment: Yes ..tried with the above answer also..but not able to perform click

Comment: Any help highly appreciated