# Selenium WebDriver: clicking piece of SVG image

Tags: javascript, java, svg, selenium-webdriver

I have code which used to work recently but not any more

```
    String xpath = "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path' and @class='zone  priceDesc_0']";
    By path = By.xpath(xpath);
    WebElement el = driver.findElement(path);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(el);

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.click(el).build().perform();
```

Now I receive an error:

```
<path>...</path> is not clickable at point (466.316650390625, 667.25). Other element would receive the click: <tspan x="" y="" class=""></tspan>
```

According to what I have found in other topics here I have changed part which clicks to:

```
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el);
```

and now I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: arguments[0].click is not a function
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: SVG paths are clickable. Can you debug and see what are you getting in WebElement el = driver.findElement(path); Is there a change in the SVG itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)