# How to identify and click this download-data-link using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

```
<span class="download-data-link"><a download="" target"_blank"="" style="cursor:pointer">Download file in csv format</a></span>
```

I need to click on the "Download file in csv format" but it always shows error that item is not clickable at that point click to see the screenshot :

[image]

I have tried all these

```
element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='download-data-link']/span"));
element.click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'data:application/csv;')]")));
link.click();

element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='alt']/span[@class='download-data-link']"));
element.click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(a[class='download-data-link']span)).click();

driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-applicationname_ModalDialog_0");
element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download file in csv format"));
element.click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

element = driver.findElement(By.className("downoad-data-link"));
element.click();
```

its my final year project ...

website : https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/indices/historical_index_data.htm

Comment: At which step are you stuck exactly? Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: after i click the get data button the table came then i need to click on download file in csv  ... i cant click this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use action class for same,

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='download-data-link']//a"))).click().perform();
```

OR

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='download-data-link']//a")));
```

Comment: what is the header file for actions??

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

Comment: nothing is happening .. its going for the next input without downloading the csv fie

Comment: Yes, because <a> is containing download actions. 
Please up vote the answer and accept it, So other readers might use it.

Comment: yes i have voted but as i am new to this and don't have 15 reputations they wont show it

Answer (score 0):

To click on the link with text as **Download file in csv format** you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- **cssSelector** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.download-data-link>a")).click();
  ```
- **xpath** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='download-data-link']/a")).click;
  ```

---

### Update A

I am still not sure why you were stuck  with the `click()` on the link with text as **Download file in csv format**. I was able to click on the link just by inducing a waiter for the element to be clickable as follows :

- Sample Code :

  ```
  package demo;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class Q50035477_click_link {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/indices/historical_index_data.htm");
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.textboxdata.hasDatepicker#fromDate")).sendKeys("23-04-2018");
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.textboxdata.hasDatepicker#toDate")).sendKeys("25-04-2018");
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.getdata-button")).click();
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Download file in csv format"))).click();
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Client Snapshot :

[image: data_csc]

**Note** : `click()` method is **robust**, **powerful** and **proven**. You should try to utilize the `click()` method in a proper way and in proper condition to avoid deviations. Of-coarse *Actions* class and *JavascriptExecutor* interface have their own usability and are used extensively.

---

### Update B

Code block for larger data :

```
    package demo;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class Q50035477_click_link {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/indices/historical_index_data.htm");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.textboxdata.hasDatepicker#fromDate")).sendKeys("01-01-2017");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.textboxdata.hasDatepicker#toDate")).sendKeys("31-12-2017");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.getdata-button")).click();
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download file in csv format"));
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
            element.click();
        }
    }
```

**Note** : Browser snapshot remains the same.

Comment: error ; not clickable at point (825,690)  other element would receive click

Comment: Check this discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/katalon-error-unable-to-click-on-object-other-element-would-receive-the-cli/44724688#44724688

Comment: i have checked the whole html file there's no duplicate of this class or the link text

Comment: @MainakDeb Check my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: the problem was occurring when the gets too long for example for a years data the error was occurring .. your code is fine for the time period u have given but it will give error if the dates are made 01-01-2017 to 31-12-2017

Comment: i need another help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037432/how-to-export-html-tabe-data-displayed-in-an-web-page-to-csv-format   please check sir ..

Comment: @MainakDeb Check out my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: sir, please help with my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037432/how-to-export-html-tabe-data-displayed-in-an-web-page-to-csv-format

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on **GetData** button , you need to scroll down and then you can interact with the WebElement, here is the full code for your requirement:

**Code :**

public class M{

```
static WebDriver driver;
static WebDriverWait wait;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation_Learning\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/indices/historical_index_data.htm");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='content']"))));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[class$='hasDatepicker'][id='fromDate']")));
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class$='hasDatepicker'][id='fromDate']")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"))));
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-datepicker-month")).click();
        selectDate(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-datepicker-month")),"Jan" );
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-datepicker-year")).click();
        selectDate(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-datepicker-year")), "2017");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']/descendant::td[contains(@class,'ui-datepicker-week-end')]/a[text()='1']")).click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[class$='hasDatepicker'][id='toDate']")));
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class$='hasDatepicker'][id='toDate']")).click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"))));

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-datepicker-month")).click();
        selectDate(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-datepicker-month")),"Dec");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-datepicker-year")).click();
        selectDate(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-datepicker-year")), "2017");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']/descendant::td[contains(@class,'ui-datepicker-week-end')]/a[text()='31']")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("get")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("get")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class$='data-historic']"))));


        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform();;

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Download file in csv format")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download file in csv format")).click();
}

    public static void selectDate(WebElement element , String textToBeSelected){
        Select select = new Select(element);
        select.selectByVisibleText(textToBeSelected);
    }
```

}

Comment: it is working for a short span of date ... when i need a years data it is not working

Comment: It is because of the Xpath I have written :

Comment: Tell me the dates from where to where you wanna select ?

Comment: The Current code would select the first date as 1-Apr-2018 and end date would be 22-Apr-2018

Comment: 01-01-2017 to 31-12-2017   take these dates as strings and then put it in the seector

Comment: could u please help ... i have taken the inputs for 1 year its not working

Comment: i have got what i needed ..but if u please update the code for 1 year using css selector or by linktext or by partial ink text it would be helpful

Comment: but as its working with js executer  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='download-data-link']//a")));

Comment: I have written code for 1 year also , just give me 2 mins.

Comment: Now I made some serious changes in code and it's working extremely fine in my system , I have used actions class and doing CTRL+END to get to the download button.You can try this code , it stable.

Comment: to interact with keyborads actions

Comment: yes its working thanks ....... and i understood the procedure ... can u help me in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037432/how-to-export-html-tabe-data-displayed-in-an-web-page-to-csv-format