# how to export html table data displayed in web page to .csv format

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jsoup, selenium-chromedriver

How to export the table `(table id="cross_rate_markets_stocks_1")` at https://in.investing.com/equities/india
after selecting any option from the drop down menu the table that is coming needed to be saved it in .csv format.

it's for my final year project . I have tried using 3rd party websites but it is capturing all the data of the site but i only need data of `(table id="cross_rate_markets_stocks_1")`

1. firstly one need to select any value from the drop down with default value BSE Sensex 30
2. then the all the data displayed on the table (table id="cross_rate_markets_stocks_1") needed to be copied to a csv fie or downloaded
   as csv file.

Comment: provide the steps manually , and desire output.

Comment: select dropdown value one by one i will do it by                                 element = driver.findElement(By.id("stocksFilter"));
      Select dropdown= new Select(element);
   System.out.println(name);
   dropdown.selectByVisibleText(name);                                                  where name contains the dropdown element  name     then i need to download the table generated for the value

Comment: did u get it ?? @cruisepandey

Comment: 1. open https://in.investing.com/equities/india 2. Click on dropDown 3. select something 4. then what you wanna do ?

Comment: then i need to copy all the data present in the table  (table id="cross_rate_markets_stocks_1") to a csv file ...

Comment: @MainakDeb Can you update the question with the _Manual Steps_ you would like to _Automate_ to _copy all the data present in the table (table id="cross_rate_markets_stocks_1") to a csv file_?

Comment: i need to open the site mentioned above , then i need to select the options from the drop down (left side drop down containing BSE Sensex 30 as default)  and then download or take a copy of all the data displayed in the table (table id="cross_rate_markets_stocks_1")

Comment: @DebanjanB sir i have updated my question

Comment: @MainakDeb Question still remains, how would you download or copy? Update the steps. Is there any element which will download or copy?

Comment: yes sir i need to download all the data present in the table (table id="cross_rate_markets_stocks_1") and how would i download i don't know as there is no seperate option for downloading the table

Comment: @DebanjanB is it even possible to download al the data without any dedicated element for download

Comment: @cruisepandey please help if u can

Comment: @MainakDeb IMHO, I can't comment right away perhaps there should be some control/element on either of the webpages on the website which should fetch you the desired result. You need to find the control. Another workaround would be to scrap the data.

Comment: @DebanjanB but there is'nt any ... the table is read only and i have to copy all that data to a csv file and save it ...  is there any way by which i can copy the data displayed in the table and save it in csv file .