# Trying to click button on selenium in python. Other element would receive the click error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click the "Easy Apply button" on the linkedin jobs search page (the beta variable)

```
alpha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.//span='Expand LinkedIn Features facet']")
alpha.click()
time.sleep(2)
beta = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")
time.sleep(4)
beta.click()
```

With this code I got the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input type="checkbox" value="f_AL" name="linkedin-features-group" id="ember1311" class="search-s-facet-value__input"> is not clickable at point (322, 146). Other element would receive the click: <div id="ember2440" class="pt3 ember-view">...</div>
```

I tried this as, well as trying to go by id(which changes every time i run the script so that didn't end up working).

Comment: The `<div id="ember2440" class="pt3 ember-view">` element is blocking your click.. find out what that is and take care of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Comment: Sorry, I thought getting flagged as a duplicate would get my question deleted

Answer (score 0):

You can use action method to solve it,

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement("element name").click().perform();
```