# how can i close iframe popup in selenium

Tags: selenium, iframe, popup

```
    iframe name="_ifrm" id="_ifrm" src="/air/wfw/html/iframe/about.html"  
    title="_ifrm" height="368px" width="800" style="border:0;overflow- 
    y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
    allowtransparency="true">

    div class="k1_yb_pop_wrap" style="width: 800px; background-color: 
    rgb(255, 255, 255);">

    class="k1_tac"      
    button class="k1_yb_btn k1_yb_btn_black k1_yb_btn_large" 
    type="button" onclick="airfn_confirm_1100100016('Y')" accept

    a class="close_pop" onclick="airfn_confirm_1100100016('N')"> closed
```

and I tried closing the pop up with this code :

```
    driver.switchTo().frame(Common.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"_ifrm\"]")));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/p[2]/button")).click() ;
```

but, Test in error is ,

```
unknown error: Element <iframe name="_ifrm" id="_ifrm" 
src="/air/wfw/html/iframe/about.html" title="_ifrm" height="368px" 
width="800" style="border:0;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;" 
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" 
cd_frame_id_="01a42b9f9d1324c7bbec7a74e48a673b"></iframe> is not 
clickable at point (591, 390). Other element would receive the click: 
<div class="list_loading">...</div>(..)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about scenario ? Iframe pop up ?

Comment: I had tried click a accept button or closed button,
but both way response is not clickable at point...

Comment: accept button or close button is on alert or in any iframe ?

Comment: no only text and accept, close button is on iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Some overlay is blocking to interact with the frame. You may need to wait till overlay or loader to go off the screen or page. You can try the following code, it may help you.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("list_loading")));

driver.switchTo().frame(Common.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"_ifrm\"]")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/p[2]/button")).click() ;
```