# click on anchor tag having href = '#'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using below python code using selenium. click is not working on anchor tag having href = "#"

```
import time    
import unittest   
from selenium import webdriver   
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By   
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select   
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys   

driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\chromedriver.exe")   
driver.get('file:///E:/Selenium/validateTest.html')     

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='validateData']/i[text()=' Validate Data']").click()
```

Here is the web html code that I am using.

```html
<h1>Anchor tag</h1>

<a href="#" class="button js-button" role="button">Show content</a>

<a href="#" id="validateData" class="btn btn-red" onclick="document.write(5 + 6)"><i class="fa fa-binoculars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Validate Data</a>
```

Comment: give the link which you want to redirect your page instead of "#"..

Comment: those are non existence link , you would have to provide the location of html files in href attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared it seems the *AUT* is based on *JavaScript*, so to click on the link with text as **Validate Data** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable and you can use either of the following options :

- `LINK_TEXT` :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Validate Data"))).click()
  ```
- `CSS_SELECTOR` :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-red#validateData"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH` :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-red' and @id='validateData']"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You will require the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB. I am getting another now.  
  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a href="#" id="validateData" class="btn btn-red" onclick="validateAllData()">...</a> is not clickable at point (88, 460). Other element would receive the click: <div id="loading-wrapper" class="">...</div>

Comment: @user3157061 _Element is not clickable_ is pretty common issue and you can solve it easily following the discussion [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y) Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv/44724688#44724688) or [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el/44916498#44916498)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a javascript executor to click your element.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
WebElement elementToClick = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='validateData']/i[text()=' Validate Data']");
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
```

Above code needs to be adapted to python ( which i'm not familiar with, but you get the idea)

Hope this helps

Comment: I am getting this error now: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a href="#" id="validateData" class="btn btn-red" onclick="validateAllData()">...</a> is not clickable at point (88, 460). Other element would receive the click: <div id="loading-wrapper" class="">...</div>