# Python selenium "Not Clickable at point error."

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

Game_Pin = input('Enter your PIN: ')
NickNAME = input('Enter your nickname: ')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver.exe")

def Enter_Press(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Enter')]").click()

def OK_GO(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-greyscale join ng-binding']").click()


def Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME, driver):
    driver.get('https://kahoot.it/')
    driver.maximize_window() #For maximizing window
    driver.implicitly_wait(2) #gives an implicit wait for 2 seconds

    game_pin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputSession']")
    game_pin.send_keys(Game_Pin)
    Enter_Press(driver)

    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']")
    Name.send_keys(NickNAME)
    OK_GO(driver)




Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME, driver)
```

The program works fine until you get to a certain point. Then selenium cannot click a button. It gives me this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <button type="submit" class="btn btn-greyscale join ng-binding" blocking="" data-functional-selector="join-button-username">...</button> is not clickable at point (1279, 741). Other element would receive the click: <div id="waitOverlay" class="alert-fullscreen valignwrapper" data-functional-selector="wait-overlay" style="opacity: 0.7;">...</div>
```

Here is the code for the button I am trying to click.

```
<button class="btn btn-greyscale join ng-binding" type="submit" data-functional-selector="join-button-username" blocking="">            OK, go!          </button>
```

Comment: try to use submit() method.

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/katalon-error-unable-to-click-on-object-other-element-would-receive-the-cli/44724688#44724688

Answer (score 1):

You can use action class to resolve this exception,

```
action=ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element("Your element").click().build().perform()
```

Comment: Note for others: I needed to remove build() for this to work for my application.

Answer (score 0):

You use `implicitly_wait` as a wrong way. In selenium `implicitly wait` is for setting the find duration of all selenium find API, like `find_element_by_xxx`.  Rather than used for waiting page refresh/load complete.

From the error message we can know, when you click on the `Go` button, but another element (A layer display loading which at top of the `GO` button ) received the click event.

So you need to wait the `loading` layer disappear before click anything covered by it.

```
Enter_Press(driver)

// driver.implicitly_wait(2) 
// remove above 'implicitly_wait' line, 
// you set the find duration to 2 seconds, the default value is 10 seconds. 
// we don't recommend to change this default value, unless you are doing 
// performance testing to expect the element comes out on page in short time.
// Selenium will return the find result once it found before 10 seconds, 
// otherwise throw `NoSuchElementException` if exceed 10 seconds.

diver.wait(xxx) // or simply use sleep() to wait the `loading` disappear.

Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']")
Name.send_keys(NickNAME)
OK_GO(driver)
```