# How to Error Handling Selenium can't click element because other element obscures it in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used [DebanjanB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44724688/7326714), but it didn't solve the error:

> Element  is not clickable at point (860.5999755859375,36.69999694824219) because another element  obscures it.

```
IWebDriver MyDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebElement Element1 = MyDriver.FindElement((By.XPath("//a[@class='pagination-button pagination-button--next']")));
//IWebElement Element1 = MyDriver.FindElement((By.XPath("//html/body/main/div/div/div[3]/section[2]/header/div[1]/ul/li/a[@class='pagination-button pagination-button--next']")));
Element1.Click();
```

I get the error once in about ten times.

Comment: What is obscuring the element? You need to deal with that... there's no one size fits all for that. Approach it like a user would... what would a user do to fix the situation? Is it a dialog? Close it. Is it a Loading... screen? Wait for it to appear and then disappear... the list goes on. Update your question with more info and the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you tried to use was Java. You've posted this under C#. If the element is obscured and doesn't go away (the overlapping element) e.g. a loading screen use javascript to delete it from the dom then click.

This should work. please replace my button with your identifier

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(myButton));
```

Edit:

Don't forget to actually click the element.

```
element.click();
```

Comment: Also, see DebanjanB's answer #6 for `javaScriptExecutor`.

Comment: not work,again error same

Comment: I would need to see the code. Does it tell what element is blocking it? Use selenium to detect the element that is obscuring the one you want to click when detected delete it using javascript so nothing is obscuring your element. Send me the full error log and I'll write the code.

Comment: ok my friend...