# Selenium for VBA - element not found error

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using a code since long time , but recently there is a new banner up which is hiding the element that I am trying to click. 
Attaching the snapshot of error. The only help I need is I need to click the hidden element( if the browser window is maximized the element is visible).

[image: error image].

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! You'll be more likely to get help if you were to [edit] your question to include the problematic code, as well as the section of html that changed, and he attempt that you've made to solve the issue on your own.  (See "[ask]" as well as how to create a [mcve].)

Comment: Please insert code between code tags not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you have said is true then you can use the following to maximize the window before clicking:

```
driver.Window.Maximize
```

Other options include:

1) Removing the banner 
2) Scrolling the element into view

Can't write anything decent for those last two as your code is an image and I don't have a full URL to test with. You also haven't included the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The "div.container-fluid" element is blocking the button you are trying to click.
You could try some of the following (as being shown here [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv/44724688#44724688)):

1. prolong the wait before the click
2. use javascript executor