# Selenium element is not clickable at point issue- Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a basic automated test in python using selenium. I can navigate through several pages but when i get to this one particular page i'm unable to click on the button.

Code where my test is failing

```
driver.find_element_by_id('//*[@id="save"]').click()
```

Element when i inspect over the button i'm trying to click

```
<input type="submit" value="View Report" id="save" name="save" data-reportid="108">
```

Error message below

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
> element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at
> point (1750, 770). Other element would receive the click:
>
> ...
>       (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)

Comment: It should `.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="save"]')` not `.find_element_by_id('//*[@id="save"]')`

Comment: Still an issue even with it updated to xpath

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Selenium was not clicking a text field that I needed it to click and raising the same `ElementClickInterceptedException`.

What worked for me was changing the approach:

The element IS THERE. It is already loaded. I made sure of it by using (in my example):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "code")))
```

Ok, so then the problem is that Selenium is failing to click on it. We can use a different strategy: Using JS!

After you have the element clickable with the `.until()` above, remember to store the field in a variable, either by using the method above:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='save' and @name='save'][@value='View Report']")))`
```

(without calling `.click()`

or by finding it:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='save' and @name='save'][@value='View Report']")
```

and then the golden part: clicking on it through JS:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', button)
```

Worked for me, see if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

first, get your windows size:

```
driver.get_window_size()
```

if your window size less than your clickable area (clickable at point (width=1750, height=770)), you need to resize your selenium driver's windows size;

```
driver.set_window_size(1750,800)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a couple of things here. As per the HTML of the element:

```
<input type="submit" value="View Report" id="save" name="save" data-reportid="108">
```

The [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element. So click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#save[name='save'][value='View Report']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='save' and @name='save'][@value='View Report']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussion in:

- [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem/44916498#44916498)
- [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)… Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/katalon-error-unable-to-click-on-object-other-element-would-receive-the-cli/44724688#44724688)

Comment: I get the following error after trying the xpath option     WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by.xpath, "//input[@id='save' and @name='save'][@value='View Report']"))).click()
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_clickable'

Comment: @PythonCoder4_09 It's not `by` but it's **`By`**

Comment: So i updated my code to `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.xpath, "//input[@id='save' and @name='save'][@value='View Report']"))).click()` Still get the same error AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_clickable' @DebanjanB

Comment: Sorry i forgot to import one of the packages. Been corrected now but i still get this issue when i run the xpath or css selector `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (482, 946)
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)` @DebanjanB

Comment: @PythonCoder4_09 Can you update the question with the complete error stack trace please?

Answer (score 0):

Element probably is covered by header or footer when selenium scroll to it. Try before your click scroll page up.

```
 JavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, 0);");
```

Comment: Would this come after i use the xpath to find the location?

Comment: Scroll before locate element