# Python Selenium error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a table with few rows where I have SiteName 1,2 and so on and next to each site name I have Edit button. I want to have a loop which clicks on all Edit buttons. However I get error when I want to click on some buttons and only on some are working properly however the code for all rows is exactly the same as you can see this example bellow.

```
wls = ["//*[contains(text(), 'SiteName 8')]//following-sibling::td//a[contains(., 'Edit')]",
       "//*[contains(text(), 'SiteName 2')]//following-sibling::td//a[contains(., 'Edit')]",
       "//*[contains(text(), 'SiteName 1')]//following-sibling::td//a[contains(., 'Edit')]"]

for i in wls:
    # WL list
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(i).click()
```

this is the following-sibling I am using and it works for Site 1,2,3 and so on but not for site 8.

I get this error message message:

> **selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (1783, 946). Other element would receive the click: ...**

I also tried just to find the full xpath and still get the same error message however the button Edit is clickable and link is valid and working.

```
<tr>
  <td class="application_name alt" align="left">SiteName 1</td><td class="alt action">
   <div class="list-action">
    <a class="btn default " href="https://link1.com">
        <i class="fa fa-fa fa-edit">::before</i>
            Edit    
     </a>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="application_name alt" align="left">SiteName 8</td>
  <td class="alt action"><div class="list-action">
   <a class="btn default " href="https://link8.com">
    <i class="fa fa-fa fa-edit">::before</i>
            Edit    
   </a>
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: I can but won't be possible for you to open it since it's local only.

Comment: @bbfl Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/katalon-error-unable-to-click-on-object-other-element-would-receive-the-cli/44724688#44724688) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem/44916498#44916498) discussion.

Comment: Basically if it's overlapping we use javascript executioner and if it's in a iframe we switch to that beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java script executioner click instead of click method.

```
for i in wls: # WL list
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath(i))
```