# id="loginbutton" name="login" tabindex="0" type="submit">...</button> is not clickable at point (600, 341). Can't click on login button on Facebook

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import time 

PATH = "/Users/khizarm/Downloads/chromedriver" 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("facebook.com/login/") 
email = driver.find_element_by_id('email') 
email.send_keys('MY EMAIL') 
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys('MY PASSWORD') 
driver.find_element_by_name('login').click()
```

Exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 _52e0 _4jy6 _4jy1 selected _51sy" id="loginbutton" name="login" tabindex="0" type="submit">...</button> is not clickable at point (600, 341). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Comment: Please check the solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until fields where you input data are clickable.

Also, you need to input an email in a correct format.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email")))
email = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
email.send_keys('myemail@sometest.com')
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys('MY PASSWORD')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#loginbutton")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginbutton').click()
```

You can also use `driver.find_element_by_id` with `loginbutton` locator.