# Element not clickable being blocked still fails using ExpectedConditions

Tags: c#, selenium

Using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers nuget pkg

Trying to click a button on a page but as the page is loading there is a sort of blocking div that is causing an error.  I noticed that if I just gradually step through the code, things work as expected, but when I just let the code run, I catch an exception that mentions something is blocking it.  Browsing the site I can see the blocking div occasionally.  First I tried just using a wait, and that was when I discovered the error, but when using ExpectedConditions I am still getting it.  What cam I missing?

```
                IWebElement dtLink = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45))
           .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(date_link_path)));
                dtLink .Click();
```

The exception message mentions this:

```
...is not clickable at point (115,311) ...because another element obscures it
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916498/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44724688/7429447) discussion helps you?

Answer (score 1):

When this error occurs there are 2 main ways to deal with that:

1. It is your way that you already did it.
2. Using 'Javascript' executor it will definitely work.
   Here it is code example:

   ```
   IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver ; 
      executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", dtLink);
   ```