Selenium - element click intercepted: Element is not clickable
I am facing an issue with some buttons. They are not clickable.
For example:
Click this button:
enter image description here
on https://generator.ninja/games/random-cards/
For some reasons, it's not clickable by driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(css)).click();.
Although, I managed to click it by using
WebElement element = css(".Button-module--btn--2EgyS:nth-child(4) > .Button-module--btnText--3a3Hp");
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

The problem is I do not understand why it's not clickable in the first place.
I tried searching for the root of the problem, but to no avail.

Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44724688/7598774

I managed to solve it, I found two solutions:

Scroll down:
 jsExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)", "");


Accept the cookies pop-up window:
 driver.findElement(By.id("rcc-confirm-button")).click();



However, I still do not understand why that is necessary, and when it's necessary.
Also, I ran into another problem; it doesn't scroll all the way down.

I'm not sure what issue you are running into. The code below works fine for me.
String url = "https://generator.ninja/games/random-cards/";
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Generate Another Playing Card']"))).click();


I tried your provided code and it didn't work for me
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span class="Button-module--btnText--3a3Hp">...</span> is not clickable at point (782, 654). Other element would receive the click: <div class="" style="flex: 1 0 300px; margin: 15px;">...</div>

